# Phonegap 3.3.0 can't access the camera on Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

#### The Problem

I am trying to make an application that uses the Camera API based on the documentation's full example here : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

I am using phonegap version 3.3.0. But it doesn't seem to work on my Android Device (Android 4.2 Jelly Bean)

#### What I have tried

- I have set the cameraOptions as follows :

  ```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { 
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100
  });
  ```
- I even tried getting a picture with an input using :

  ```
   < input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" >
  ```

  but nothing worked.

**If you have any ideas please help.**

Comment: have you installed the camera plugin?

Comment: Yes I have. Thanks for your quick reply, I solved it. I used to create a project with the cordova command line, add the necessary plugins and upload it to phonegap build and it didn't work. But when I built it with cordova and ran it on the device directly it did work. I am kinda new to phonegap. Thanks again .

Comment: Does that mean that if you use Adobe's PhoneGap Build it won't work? Does this problem exist for current Android OSes or just the Jelly Bean one? Thanks.